# In Java where do the static methods go during the creation of an object in java?

Tags: java, heap-memory, static-methods

If there is a class with some methods, whenever we create a new object then that object gets created on the heap with the fields and methods. If we have a class with static and normal methods and we create an object of this class, the instance variables and normal methods still exist but how are the static methods created ?

Comment: You need to revisit your first assumption: an *object* doesn't contain methods at all. It's not part of the *state* of the object.

Comment: Then where does the method code exist since we place a call to the method. Are there two spaces called the program space and the data space. And when we place a call to a method, the instance variables are copied from the data space to the registers and the program counter points to the begin address of the method from the program space.

Comment: Each object has information saying its actual type, and the JVM associates that with the methods. But it would be pointless and *really* wasteful to have to populate an object with the same information as all the other objects of the same type. (Think of all the methods in `java.lang.String` - do you really want every string object to separately contain copies of some representation of each method?)

Answer (score 3):

All methods, both static and non-static, are part of the *class*, and classes are stored in non-heap memory.

All that resides in the heap is a structure containing:

- a pointer to the class of which this object is an instance
- The current values for each non-static field (references for object fields, values for primitive fields)

So for example:

```
 public class Person {
     private String name;
     private int age;

     public String getName() {
         return name;
     }

     // ... etc.
 }
```

**One** structure in non-heap memory contains:

- Metadata about the class e.g. its name `Person`, a pointer to its superclass etc.
- The bytecode for `getName()` and any other methods
- JIT optimised versions of the bytecode

For each *instance* of `Person`, we get in the heap:

- A reference to the class entry
- An int value for `age`
- A reference to a `String` object `name`

So, at least conceptually, you could see the runtime handling a call to `aPerson.getName()` as:

- Look at the object's record in heap
- Follow the reference to its class
- In the class, find the method `getName()`
- Run the method, using the object's record in the heap for fields

This means that if you have 1000 instances of `Person`, you still only have one copy of the code from the class, which is perfect because it does not change from one instance to the next.

If `Doctor`, `Nurse`, `Patient` are all subclasses of `Person`, and if none of them override `getName()`, then the code for `getName()` still only exists once in memory. (Conceptually) when you call `aNurse.getName()` the runtime will look in `Nurse` for `getName()`, if found, run that, otherwise look in the superclass `Person`, find it, and run that.

---

I've said "conceptually" a couple of times. In reality some of what I've described as happening dynamically may happen statically at compile time. This doesn't really matter as far as understanding the effect on memory and performance.